# Including multiple files calling the same definiton file

Tags: php, oop

I'm having trouble with the `require_once` code.

I have a file called `definitions.php` and it stores all my basic DEFINE's such as database password, username, some links, etc...

Then I have a file called `config.php`, where I have basic classes built, and I call the `definitions.php` with `require_once` from this file.

Then I have multiple files, storing the extensions of the basic classes and functions that I use.

I would like to have a file `includes.php`, where all these files are listed, so that on the page, I only call the `includes.php`.

I have tried just listing the files in the file `includes.php` with `require_once` but I got an error that DEFINE's are already defined.

Comment: check your code if perhaps some of the calls is include() or require() without _once

Comment: Yeah thank you, that worked, i missed one of those and taught i had some other problem. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to check that have "_once" appended at the end. Missed that one. Tnx Ivan.